# Unknown Post Meta Records

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, bulk-import

I inherited a site that has had many developers. There are post meta custom post type records for custom post types that we do not have. They appear to have come in through an import when the site was rebuilt in a new host and new theme. Is there a way to remove records in post meta that don't tie to any of our software without breaking the Wordpress Core?

Additional Information Update
The records in the postmeta table are tied to active posts and pages. The values in the records are irrelevant to the current site.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this in **2 step**

First Step : Remove **ORPHANED UNUSED** post meta data 
(SQL Query)

```
DELETE pm FROM wp_postmeta pm
LEFT JOIN wp_posts wp ON wp.ID = pm.post_id
WHERE wp.ID IS NULL
```

Second Step **INFORMATION** :  Identify all post meta which is currently set to that post

```
$meta_values = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() );
echo '<pre>'. print_r($meta_values, 1). '</pre>';
```

if you found any extra meta, which is not used by your system you can delete it.

```
delete_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_key' );
```

Comment: I'm new at stack overflow, I don't have enough credit to give you an upvote. I will be trying this solution, thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: I see that my question was not clear, I have updated it. Thank you.